# writing file from docker container to host instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, travis-ci

So I am using Travis CI to automatically deploy my application to AWS Elasticbeanstalk environment. I have this issue that I need to update the nginx.conf file that is located in the host machine files.
Im running a Single container Docker image inside that host machine.
How can I copy or link the nginx.conf file from docker container to host machines nginx.conf file. 
Currently my Dockerrun.aws.json looks like that:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
        "Name": "some:image:url:here",
        "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
        {
            "ContainerPort": "8001"
        }
    ],
    "Volumes": [
      {
        "HostDirectory": "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf",
        "ContainerDirectory": "/home/node/app/nginx.conf"
      }
    ]
}
```

When I tried to use dockerrunversion: 2, it gave me an error on the build that version is wrong.
How can I link those two files with Single Container Docker application?

Answer (score 0):

The "Volumes" key is used to map full volumes, not individual files. See Dockerrun.aws.json [file specifications for an explanation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html).

I know of 2 ways you can solve this problem:  1) Custom AMI or 2) use a Dockerfile with your Dockerrun.aws.json.

### 1. Build a Custom AMI

The idea behind building a custom AMI is to launch an instance from one of Amazons existing AMIs.  You make the changes you need to it (in your case, change the nginx.conf).  Finally you create a new AMI from this instance and it will be available to you when you create your environment in Elastic Beanstalk.  [Here are the detailed steps to create your own AMI and how to use it with Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html).

### 2. Use a Dockerfile with your Dockerrun.aws.json

If you dont build your own AMI, you can copy your conf file with the help of a `Dockerfile`.  Dockerfile is a text file that provides commands to Elastic Beanstalk to run to build your custom image.  The [Docerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) details the commands that can be added to a Dockerfile to build your image.  You are going to need to to use [the Copy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) command or if the file is simple, you can use `Run` and `echo` to build it like in the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-singlecontainer-deploy.html#docker-singlecontainer-dockerfilesample).

Once you create your Dockerfile, you will need to put the Dockerfile and your Dockerrun.aws.json into a directory and create a zip file with both.  Provide this to Elastic Beanstalk as your source bundle.  Follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html) to build the source bundle correctly.

Comment: Where do I need to put the process of copying if I am building my image with Travis CI and uploading it to the ECS. After that the Dockerrun.aws.json file reads the image from ECS and deploys it to the Elasticbeanstalk environment. At the moment I added the line COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx . But the nginx.conf file in the host machine remained unchanged.

Comment: Can you build the conf file using shell commands (like echo and >>) ?  If so, add the commands to a shell file after_deploy.sh.  Then run them via the environment variable described in this Travis CI doc:  https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/elasticbeanstalk/#Running-commands-before-and-after-deploy

Comment: I added the Travis CI tag to this question in case one of their experts sees this question.  It might be a setting inside TravisCI.  My answer is from a pure AWS perspective.